# Restart service that manages "Windows share" folders

Tags: networking, shared-folders

I connect from Ubuntu 12.04 to a Windows 7 on another computer connected to the LAN using nautilus > File > Connect to server. Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes when I open it and try to open the Windows "Users" folder Ubuntu opens it (or try to because it hangs) with a text editor. I tried right clicking the folder and "Open with files" but it still open a text editor.

If I restart Ubuntu it works again. So I was wondering is there a service or something I could restart to fix this issue without restarting the computer?

Services status:

```
root:~$ service --status-all
 [ ? ]  acpi-support
 [ ? ]  acpid
 [ ? ]  alsa-restore
 [ ? ]  alsa-store
 [ ? ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  atd
 [ ? ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootlogd
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  cron
 [ ? ]  cups
 [ ? ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dmesg
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  failsafe-x
 [ - ]  fancontrol
 [ ? ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hddtemp
 [ ? ]  hostname
 [ ? ]  hwclock
 [ ? ]  hwclock-save
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ - ]  lm-sensors
 [ ? ]  modemmanager
 [ ? ]  module-init-tools
 [ ? ]  network-interface
 [ ? ]  network-interface-container
 [ ? ]  network-interface-security
 [ ? ]  network-manager
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  nxsensor
 [ ? ]  nxserver
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  openvpn
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ ? ]  plymouth-splash
 [ ? ]  plymouth-stop
 [ ? ]  plymouth-upstart-bridge
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  resolvconf
 [ ? ]  rfkill-restore
 [ ? ]  rfkill-store
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ ? ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  setvtrgb
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  stop-bootlogd
 [ - ]  stop-bootlogd-single
 [ ? ]  sudo
 [ ? ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-fallback-graphics
 [ ? ]  udev-finish
 [ ? ]  udevmonitor
 [ ? ]  udevtrigger
 [ ? ]  ufw
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ ? ]  virtualbox
 [ ? ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: could you try `sudo service samba restart`?

Comment: @adempewolff Tried that but I get "unrecognized service", same thing happens with smb, smbd, etc.

Comment: Ah, i misread the from...to... order in your question.  While you have the Windows share mounted could you please paste the output of `service --status-all`? I don't know the name of the service that mounts Windows shares but I'm guessing it will have either `cifs` or `smbfs` in the name.

Comment: @adempewolff i added the services status on the question, I don't seem to have either cifs or smbfs. The windows folders were mounted when i ran the "services --status-all" command.